# Create bucket for public access with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a bucket programmatically as follows:

```java
String bucketName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

List<Acl> aclList = new ArrayList<>();
if (gcsBucketEntity.isPublic()) {
    Acl publicAccessAcl = Acl.newBuilder(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER).build();
    aclList.add(publicAccessAcl);
}

BucketInfo bucketInfo = BucketInfo
        .newBuilder(bucketName)
        .setLocation(gcsBucketEntity.getLocation()) // Multi-regions
        .setStorageClass(valueOfStrict(gcsBucketEntity.getStorageType().toString()))
        .setAcl(aclList)
        .build();

Bucket bucket = this.storage.create(bucketInfo);
```

I have also tried to set a `BucketTargetOption` instead:

```java
Storage.BucketTargetOption bucketTargetOption = Storage.BucketTargetOption
        .predefinedAcl(Storage.PredefinedAcl.PUBLIC_READ);

Bucket bucket = this.storage.create(bucketInfo, bucketTargetOption);
```

with the exact same result.

The bucket is created and in the GCP console I can see that the access is public.

However, I am not able to access any files and I get a `AccessDenied` error instead:

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access denied.</Message>
  <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details>
</Error>
```

If I create the bucker manually I think I have to add a `Storage Object Viewer` role to the user `allUsers`:

[image]

This is the only difference I can see between the manually and automatically created bucket so my question is..

How do I add this permission programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an example in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#code-samples_1).

Apparently we have to create the bucket first and set the IAM-policy afterwards.

```java
BucketInfo bucketInfo = BucketInfo
        .newBuilder(bucketName)
        .setLocation(gcsBucketEntity.getLocation()) // Multi-regions
        .setStorageClass(valueOfStrict(gcsBucketEntity.getStorageType().toString()))
        .build();

Bucket bucket = this.storage.create(bucketInfo);

if (gcsBucketEntity.isPublic()) {
    Policy policy = this.storage.getIamPolicy(bucketName);
    this.storage.setIamPolicy(
            bucket.getName(),
            policy.toBuilder()
                    .addIdentity(StorageRoles.objectViewer(), Identity.allUsers())
                    .build()
    );
}
```

This is a bit odd imho because if something goes wrong I might end up with a "broken" bucket.

Anyway, the above code works for me.